# What is the meaning of symbols: $\Omega$ is $C^2$ and $u(t,x) \in L^p(0,T;L^q(\mathbb{R}^n))$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What does it mean when we say the domain $\Omega$ is $C^2$? (For example, in [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_boundary_value_problem#Strong_solutions))

And what does it mean when we say the function $u(t,x) \in L^p(0,T;L^q(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Comment: For your second question, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space)

Comment: oh, very tanks ... It must be true. what is your opinion about the next question?